# Acessar um método de Form para outro Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, classes, método

Eu tenho um Método `carregarLista()` em formulário chamando `Funcionarios`, e gostaria de acessar esse método de outro `Form` chamado `Cancelar`. O método está publico no `Form` `Funcionarios`, só que mesmo assim não consigo acessar ele do `Cancelar`.

```
public void carregarLista()
    {

        comboList.Items.Clear();
        sqlCommand.Connection  =  conexão.Conectar();
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM CadFuncionário";
        dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                comboList.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());

            }
        }
        conexão.Desconectar();
        txtNome.Clear();
    }
```

Fiz a instância do Form Funcionários dentro do Form Cancelar só que mesmo assim não tenho acesso ao método.

```
Funcionarios funcionarios = new Funcionarios();
```

Comment: É só setar ele como public ou internal.

Comment: Eu não tinha lido que já está como público, foi mal. Você consegue reproduzir isso num exemplo mínimo e postar o código?

Answer (score 1):

O grande problema estrutural é que isso tem uma responsabilidade que é organizar os dados que são pegos do banco de dados, pelo menos o grosso do código é isso. O que foge dessa responsabilidade é o `comboList.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());`.

Esse código deveria ser parte de outro objeto que cuida do modelo e não da visão (a UI). Se fosse separado poderia chamar de onde quiser. Não é simples fazer isso certo, para ter performance teria que usar mecanismos avançados que muitos não conhecem ou dominam, mas é o correto.

Essa forma que está fazendo é o mesmo feito por muita gente e em algo simples vai bem, mas é gambiarra, sempre foi, mesmo que quase todo mundo faça assim.

Se ainda quiser insistir na gambiarra e deixar tudo pior, mas que funcione (estou explicitamente não recomendando fazer isso, mas sei que fará), pode parametrizar esse método para poder usar de forma mais genérica. Isso se realmente o método faz exatamente o que deseja sem mudar nada. Esse parâmetro seria o `comboList` que você passaria sempre, nesse formulário ou no outro. Você não pode usar sem o parâmetro porque nesse método atual o `comboList` na verdade é o `this.comboList` e você não quer isso se for usar em outro formulário.

Ainda teria que ver o que fazer com o `txtNome` que tem o mesmo problema, será que deve parametrizá-lo também? Provavelmente sim.

Já falei que chamar um método de um formulário, e que parece ser detalhe de implementação e por isso privado, então torná-lo público já é um outro erro, e que tudo isso é gambiarra da grossa?

Pra falar a verdade é menos gambiarra copiar e colar esse código lá no outro formulário. Não é que seja bom, mas causa menos problema.

Esse código tem outros problemas e vaza recurso em algumas situações, ainda que não seja perceptível na maioria delas. Ese padrão de reinventar abertura de conexão foi ensinado por alguém um dia e todo mundo passou fazer errado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples para fazer isso é criar uma instância estática de funcionários no próprio script de funcionários assim:

```
class Funcionarios : Form
{
    //Passo 1: Declarar váriavel public e static:
    public static Funcionarios funInstancia;

    public Funcionarios()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Passo 2: Atribuir this (o objeto/formulário) para funInstancia
        funInstancia = this;
    }

    public void CarregarLista()
    {
        //etc etc...
    }
}
```

E depois basta acessar a variável static da classe Funcionarios de qualquer lugar assim:

```
//Para acessar a variável/objeto
Funcionarios.funInstancia. // .qualquer método, objeto, controle, etc que for público

//Para acessar o método "CarregarLista"
Funcionarios.funInstancia.CarregarLista();
```

Comment: Tá, isso pode ser uma certa gambiarrinha mas POR ENQUANTO fuciona.